# Is it totally reckless to leave mysql connection open through a page?

Tags: php, mysql

When querying the db is it plausible to feel extremely paranoid? I go as far as opening and closing mysql connection every time a new query has to be done. I am afraid that (especially with the ajax enabled pages) this would cause great performance downgrading.

Should I continue in this method or at least open and close connections once in everypage (instead of per-query)? (i'm writing in php btw)

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the overhead of connecting every time will be considerable. I suggest you just close it when you're done, it's very unlikely that simply having an open connection without running queries on it will open you to vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend a connection pool if it's possible with PHP.  It's a way to simultaneously maximize performance and minimize connection time.

Comment: Though not really a connection pool, PHP can maintain a persistent connection for each Apache worker via mysql_pconnect().

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* close MySQL connections immediately. It's better to use a single connection for the entire PHP script. PHP will automatically close the connection if you don't explicitly.

Opening a new connection incurs some small time penalty, particularly if MySQL lives on another server on the network. New TCP connections require a [three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment), and each TCP connection consumes kernel resources for [at least two minutes](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=2941).

Although PHP doesn't support full-fledged connection pooling, the procedural MySQL API does support persistent connections. See [`mysql_pconnect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) for more details. At my office we use `pconnect` to avoid crashing the TCP stacks on our high-traffic PHP site.

Answer (score 0):

Consider PHP Data Objects, which can keep a persistent connection for you. You really only connect with credentials once and then cache the connection. Create the connection with something along these lines:

`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=DBNAME', 
               'USER', 'PASSWORD',
               array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));`

For more information, see [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) in the php manual.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for PHP, but when I write this kind of thing in Apache/Perl I generally do two things to boost performance:

a) allow MySQL handles to stay open as long as the Apache daemon does.
b) keep cached statement handles around (using an LRU cache).

On production servers, some of those MySQL handles have been around for days, serving many thousands of quite complicated SQL queries.  It isn't a problem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: DO make sure you either commit or rollback any transactions you may have started.